# 301 Redirect to other domain of selected deep pages only?

Tags: 301-redirect

would appreciate help on this

i am trying to 301 selected deep pages only from one domain to deep pages on another domain. I do not wish to 301 the entire site.  My questions are a) is this possible and b) what is the  full htaccess code and syntax

i.e. old.co.uk/oldurl to new.com/newurl

can I ask if this will work on its own?

redirect 301 /OldPage.html http://xyzname.com/NewPage.html

many thanks to all

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, I hope nobody gives you full .htaccess code and syntax as this is not a do-my-job-for-free website. You can find full rewrite documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I am a site owner but this is not my job, but thanks for your help so far

Comment: Then you should learn or pay someone to do it for you :).

Comment: I dont mind learning and doing it myself and have searced for resources online to learn (I know it's not hard) but none I have found so far are clear, complete and simple to follow

Comment: can I ask if this will work on its own?

Comment: Yes, you can find people that do even this kind of things on free lancing web sites. If you are really looking for someone, I can get you in touch with some people.

Comment: Also worth to mention that you should not (if possible) use .htaccess files but put the rules directly in the configuration files if you have access to them.